# EU Healthcare for an EU citizen living in the UK

Tags: health, eu-citizens, brexit

I am an italian citizen, but my residence is in the United Kingdom since 2016. I currently hold an EHIC card from Italy (which might not be "valid" anymore), and an EHIC card from the NHS (my current healthcare provider).

In the event of a no-deal Brexit, [UK citizens wouldn't have access to free healthcare in EU countries as they currently do](https://www.gov.uk/visit-europe-brexit), and they would need to travel with a health insurance (just as any other non-EU citizen).

I was wondering: would that apply for me as well? While an italian citizen (so an EU citizen), I would be a resident of a non-EU country. I would be covered in Italy because of how the italian system specifically deals with italians living abroad that temporarily visit. But if (hypothetically) I travel to France and I need urgent care in a hospital, would I get it for free? And how exactly?

Comment: EHIC cards, and health coverage generally, are based on residence, not citizenship, though apparently Italy is an exception there. Even third-country nationals residing in the UK can get EHIC cards, but I do not think that an Italian citizen residing outside the EU would be able to participate in EHIC.

Comment: I see. Well, yet another reason to hate "no deal". If you put it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: I commented rather than answering because I am unsure of how EHIC works for Italian citizens who live outside the EU in light of their ability to use health services during visits to Italy.  In other words, "I do not think that..." reflects insufficient certainty.